# How to print a child tag attribute inside a selected parent tag in xml using Java

Tags: java, xml

I have one doubt on XML File Tag print and read. 
Take an example: I want to select a particular Tag from XML File. In this I need to read and print the selected parent tag attribute and also print all child tag (rubric, div, Interaction, simpleChoice, prompt) attribute. I can able to get a parent Tag Id and I am not getting all child Tag Id.

```
public class ReadXmlId {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String filePath = "/Users/myXml/Sample.xml";
    File xmlFile = new File(filePath);
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder;
    try {
        dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(xmlFile);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        printElement(doc);
        System.out.println("XML file updated successfully");
    } catch (SAXException | ParserConfigurationException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
private static void printElement(Document someNode) {
    NodeList nodeList = someNode.getElementsByTagName("itemBody");
    Node nNode = nodeList.item(0);
    ArrayList<String> listOfArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int z=0,size= nodeList.getLength();z<size; z++) {
        //Value is variable use to print Parent Tag (itemBody) ID
            String Value = nodeList.item(z).getAttributes().getNamedItem("id").getNodeValue();
            listOfArray.add(Value);
            //Syntax to read the child tag
            NodeList nList = nNode.getChildNodes();
            for (int i = 0; i < nList.getLength();i++) {
                Node child = nList.item(i);
                if (child.getNodeType() == Document.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    if (child.getNodeName().equals("*")) {
                        //Value1 is variable use to print all child Tag (div,p,SimpleChoice and all) ID
                        String Value1 = nList.item(i).getAttributes().getNamedItem("id").getNodeValue();
                        listOfArray.add(Value1);
                        continue;

                    } else {
                         System.out.println("Empty List");  
                    }
                }

            }

      }
     System.out.println("Array List"+listOfArray);
}
```

}

Example: (id)

```html
<itemBody class="etsmcm01fmt" id="244_item_content_3">
    <rubric class="item_response_information " id="244_item_response_information_21" use="instruction" view="author proctor scorer testConstructor tutor"/>
    <xi:include xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" href="../Passage/205.qti.xml"/>
    <div class="stimulus_reference " id="244_stimulus_reference_4">
        <p class="introduction passage-intro " id="244_introduction_5">Read<span class="formatted_text text_decoration:underline " id="200244_formatted_text_6">two</span> sentences</p>
    </div>
    <Interaction class="choice_list " id="244_choice_list_12" maxChoices="4" minChoices="0" responseIdentifier="RESPONSE" shuffle="false">
        <prompt id="244_item_stem_8">
            <p class="stem_paragraph " id="244_stem_paragraph_9">story</p>
        </prompt>
        <simpleChoice class="block_choice " id="200244_block_choice_13" identifier="i1">
            <p class="choice_paragraph " id="200244_choice_paragraph_14">North and south</p>
        </simpleChoice>
        <simpleChoice class="block_choice " id="200244_block_choice_15" identifier="i2">
            <p class="choice_paragraph " id="200244_choice_paragraph_16">Sun and Moon</p>
        </simpleChoice>
        <simpleChoice class="block_choice " id="200244_block_choice_17" identifier="i3">
            <p class="choice_paragraph " id="200244_choice_paragraph_18">uncomfortable.</p>
        </simpleChoice>
        <simpleChoice class="block_choice " id="200244_block_choice_19" identifier="i4">
            <p class="choice_paragraph " id="200244_choice_paragraph_20">head.</p>
        </simpleChoice>
    </Interaction></itemBody>
```

Comment: So, what is your actual question? What problem do you have? Do you get any errors?

Comment: I think you can see the XML file above. I need to print the **ID** of each and every tag inside Parent Tag **(Item Body)**. Including the parent tag, I choose this Item Body tag a from big Xml File, which have plenty of tag.

Comment: maybe [XPath](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/xslt/xpath.html) could help

Comment: XPath: It will be used to navigate through elements and attributes in an XML document,but it will be like hard code the tag name right. Without Hard code the child tag, I need a solution. We can Hard code the parent tag(Item Body).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for a way to print all attributes of all elements inside `<itemBody>` elements.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NamedNodeMap;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;


public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException {
        File xmlFile = new File("C:\\test\\testDocXml.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder;

        dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(xmlFile);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        walkNode(doc);
    }

    private static void walkNode(Node node) {
        NodeList nodeList = node.getChildNodes();

        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            checkChildNode(nodeList.item(i));
        }
    }

    private static void checkChildNode(Node node) {
        if (node.hasChildNodes()) {
            checkAttributes(node);

            walkNode(node);
        }
    }
    private static void checkAttributes(Node node) {
        if (node.hasAttributes()) {
            NamedNodeMap attributes = node.getAttributes();

            printAttributes(attributes);
        }
    }

    private static void printAttributes(NamedNodeMap attributes) {
        for (int i = 0; i < attributes.getLength(); i++) {
            Node attribute = attributes.item(i);

            if (attribute.getNodeName() == "id") {
                System.out.println("Attribute found: " + attribute.getNodeName() + " : " + attribute.getNodeValue());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And you get an output like:

```
Attribute found: id : 244_item_content_3
Attribute found: id : 244_stimulus_reference_4
Attribute found: id : 244_introduction_5
Attribute found: id : 200244_formatted_text_6
Attribute found: id : 244_choice_list_12
Attribute found: id : 244_item_stem_8
Attribute found: id : 244_stem_paragraph_9
Attribute found: id : 200244_block_choice_13
Attribute found: id : 200244_choice_paragraph_14
Attribute found: id : 200244_block_choice_15
Attribute found: id : 200244_choice_paragraph_16
Attribute found: id : 200244_block_choice_17
Attribute found: id : 200244_choice_paragraph_18
Attribute found: id : 200244_block_choice_19
Attribute found: id : 200244_choice_paragraph_20
```

Comment: Hello, Wesley De Keirsmaeker, Thank you for your great solution to my query. **I need only the Attribute (ID)**.

Comment: I trying to get only Attribute (ID) by this method **attribute.getNamedItem("id")**.

Comment: Then add a check on the attribute.getNodaName() == "id".

Comment: If I use attribute.getNodaName() == "id". I am getting **false** on getNodeValue() as an output.

Comment: Nice.It working Great. Wesley De Keirmaeker, I will ask you another one question. If I want to get the values of attribute **id** between the Tag **<Interaction>** in the above XML, What are the code changes we need.

Answer (score 0):

To print a value of attribute **id** between the Tag **(Interaction)** in the above XML. I use Wesley code and done some simple changes.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,ParserConfigurationException, SAXException {
    String filePath = "/Users/myXml/SampleXml.xml";
    File xmlFile = new File(filePath);
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder;
    dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(xmlFile);
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        printElement(doc);
        System.out.println("XML file updated successfully");

}
private static void printElement(Document someNode) {
    NodeList nodeList = someNode.getElementsByTagName("Interaction");

    Node nNode = nodeList.item(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
        checkChildNode(nNode);
    }
}
private static void walkNode(Node node) {
    NodeList nodeList = node.getChildNodes();
    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
        checkChildNode(nodeList.item(i));
    }
}
private static void checkChildNode(Node node) {
    if (node.hasChildNodes()) {
        checkAttributes(node);
        walkNode(node);
    }
}
private static void checkAttributes(Node node) {
    if (node.hasAttributes()) {
        NamedNodeMap attributes = node.getAttributes();
        printAttributes(attributes);
    }
}
private static void printAttributes(NamedNodeMap attributes) {
    for (int i = 0; i < attributes.getLength(); i++) {
        Node attribute = attributes.item(i);
        if (attribute.getNodeName() == "id") {
        System.out.println("Attribute found: " +  attribute.getNodeName()+ " : " + attribute.getNodeValue());
        }
   }

}
```

}